# Excel COUNTIF criteria using curly brackets for logical OR not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Given the following in column A:

```
tom
bob
harry
tom2
bob
harry
tom3
bob
harry
```

I want to count "tom" OR "bob" using `=COUNTIF(A:A,{"tom","bob"})`.  However the function returns only 1 instead of 4.  If I flip the order of tom and bob in the function, I get 3.  The function is only counting the first argument inside the curly brackets.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: So tom2 and tom3 don't count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution would be two `countif` functions -

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"tom")+COUNTIF(A:A,"bob")
```

You can also use a `sumproduct` if you want the curly brackets

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A={"bob","tom"})*1)
```

or no brackets

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="bob")+(A:A="tom"))
```

And I *think* this should work -

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"bob","tom"}))
```

As [XOR LX](https://superuser.com/users/326707/xor-lx) pointed out, this one one can use `countif` instead.

Comment: The last one worked (more compact also).  Thank you!

Comment: @Marty if this solves your problem please hit the green checkmark next to it to mark your question as solved

Comment: Of course the last example does not need to use the function COUNTIFS. Simply COUNTIF will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below formula to count the number of tom and bob both.

=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:A50,{"bob","tom"}))